# How to iterate through a dataframe to format values?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a dataframe where every column has numeric values like `5,12; 3,14; 12,01...` in object dtype.
I want to iterate through the table to convert the dtype to float.
Therefore, I made a list of all column names to replace the ',' with '.' of every value and then convert it into the right type.

My code looks like this:

```
for x in columnList:
     x.replace(',' , '.') 
     x.astype(float)
```

Data:

```
Timestamp    Ins_W/m2  GenPowerW1 GenPowerW2 GenPowerW3
2020-01-01      5,12     3,14         12,1
2020-01-02      6,84                  16,4       12,1
.
.
.
```

Unfortunately, I always get an AttributeError.
I hope someone can give me a hint on how to fix it.

Comment: Could you add part of your data here, e.g. adding the output of `df.head(5)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([["1,12", "3,14", ""], ["12,1", "234,1", "21,1"]], columns=["INS", "GEN_POWER1", "GEN_POWER2"])

df[["INS", "GEN_POWER1", "GEN_POWER2"]] = df[["INS", "GEN_POWER1", "GEN_POWER2"]].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(",", "."))

df[["INS", "GEN_POWER1", "GEN_POWER2"]] = df[["INS", "GEN_POWER1", "GEN_POWER2"]].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

This applies the lambda function to each column that you need, and then converts each of those columns to a float using pd.to_numeric. The output looks like this:

```
     INS  GEN_POWER1  GEN_POWER2
0   1.12        3.14         NaN
1  12.10      234.10        21.1
```

Comment: purrrrrrfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each of the columns, converting each column to strings (with [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html)) to allow replacement and then converting those values to floats. To convert empty cells to `NaN` we first replace them with the string `'NaN'`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'Timestamp': ['2020-01-01', '2020-01-02'],
  'Ins_W/m2': ['5,12', '6,84'],
  'GenPowerW1': ['3,14', ''],
  'GenPowerW2': ['12,1', '16,4'],
  'GenPowerW3': ['', '12,1']
})
df
#      Timestamp Ins_W/m2 GenPowerW1 GenPowerW2 GenPowerW3
#  0  2020-01-01     5,12       3,14       12,1
#  1  2020-01-02     6,84                  16,4       12,1
columnList = ['Ins_W/m2', 'GenPowerW1', 'GenPowerW2', 'GenPowerW3']
for col in columnList :
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',', '.').replace('', 'NaN').astype(float)
df
#      Timestamp  Ins_W/m2  GenPowerW1  GenPowerW2  GenPowerW3
#  0  2020-01-01      5.12        3.14        12.1         NaN
#  1  2020-01-02      6.84         NaN        16.4        12.1
df['GenPowerW1']
#  0    3.14
#  1     NaN
#  Name: GenPowerW1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thx, but when i try this i get ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: @EF711 does your data not look like what I used in my example? If not, could you please edit your question to give some sample data in the same way as I have?

Comment: sorry for that i still dont know how to copy the df. i guess the problem is that there're some missing values like blank cells

Comment: @EF711 what result do you want for the blank cells? leave them blank, or convert to `0` or `NaN`?

Comment: NaN would be the best option in this case

Comment: @EF711 please see my edit. I think that should solve your problem

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort but now i get an ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: @EF711 is the data not the same as in my answer? I copied it from your question...

Comment: sorry, im not able to copy my whole df, maybe there is something that causes the error. Anyway finally it works now. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @EF711 hmmm... you must have some strange data! You can do a similar thing with this code by using `df[col] = df[col].str.replace(',', '.').apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')`